# How to Install Office 2007 Enterprise onto Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server

Tags: terminal, microsoft-office

Can you tell me how to get an Office 2007 Enterprise VLK program to work in terminal services? I keep getting an error that says

> This copy of Office cannot be used on terminal server.

I can't figure out what I'm missing

Comment: Your question will be closed shortly (I suspect), but look into [striping the check out of the MSI file with ORCA](http://www.devcha.com/2007/01/edit-operating-system-version-check-in.html).

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a VLK? Use this article to verify the Release Type: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928516

Comment: @mbrownnyc No reason to close this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)